# How can I save query results to a file without using bcp?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure to store query results without using bcp.

Will it be implemented in any way using `sp_send_dbmail` (saving file in local folder and send email attaching that file)?

Comment: `sp_send_dbmail` doesn't save a dataset and then attach the file, it simply attaches the dataset as a file (csv if i recall correctly, I never use the functionality). What you're asking is pretty broad. There are plenty of ways to save a result set to disc; `bcp`, `sqlcmd`, .Net, SSIS, Powershell, SSRS, 3rd party tools. Which you use is up to you.

Comment: How about using Powershell?